# (blueimp uploader) redirect to uploaded file after file uploaded

Tags: php, redirect, filenames, blueimp

With blueimp uploader, I can't get filenames. I try this codes

```
on("fileuploaddone", function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                alert(file.name);
            });
```

but its not working. Try "complete:", its not working, I did try many methods.

I wan't to redirect to uploaded file name (eg uploaded.jpg). Like "check_file.php?filename=?uploaded.jpg". But i can't get uploaded file name.

```
    <script>
/*jslint unparam: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ? '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'jQuery-File-Upload-master/server/php/';
    $('#fileupload')
        .fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
    var queryString = 'username=&timestamp=';
    $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
        queryString += '&file['+index+']='+file.name;
    });
    window.location.href = 'myNextPage.php?'+queryString
}

        // stop: function (e) {
        //console.log('Uploads finished');
        //window.location = "/result.php";    }

    }).on("fileuploaddone", function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                alert(file.name);
            });
        }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput).parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled')
    ;








});



</script>
```